# Un nom pour parler du caractère borné d'un objet : "bornitude" ?

Tags: mathématiques, noms, demande-de-mot

En mathématiques, on a souvent besoin de dire que quelque chose est "borné" (au sens que la chose a des bornes, des délimitations). On a en fait même souvent besoin d'un nom qui correspondrait à l'adjectif "borné", par exemple dans une phrase comme "Grâce à la [*nom qui correspond*] de la suite, [...]."

L'anglais dispose du mot "boundedness" pour ça, et en général on le traduit en français par "bornitude"... Mot qui n'existe pas. (Il n'est en tout cas dans aucun dictionnaire, à ma connaissance.) Est-ce qu'il y aurait un nom qui conviendrait dans cette situation ?

(NB : "finitude" ne convient pas, en tout cas pas en mathématiques ; je peux le dire d'avance.)

Comment: Je ne sais pas s'il y a un mot accepté ou pas; je ne le connais en tout cas pas.  Plus généralement, ce genre de problème, on le rencontre -- dans tous les sens -- quand on essaye de suivre trop fortement une formulation provenant d'une autre langue.  Il faut accepter de s'écarter du mot à mot et de reformuler la proposition, la phrase, le paragraphe.  Ici, _La suite est bornée et donc..._

Comment: Il ne s'agit pas que d'un problème de traduction, @Unfrancophone. Même pendant un exposé en français donné par un français, il arrive que l'orateur bloque dans sa phrase et finisse par utiliser le mot "bornitude" (en général les gens se mettent à rire).

Comment: I’m not sure why [finitude](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/finitude)/”finiteness” is off the table, for it’s definitely a suitable synonym for “boundedness” in English, as are “measurability”/[mesurabilité](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/mesurabilit%C3%A9) & “determinability”/[determinabilité](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/determinabilit%C3%A9). Are they off the table, too? The nouns "finiteness/infiniteness" have meaning in math in English & I’m surprised that their French equivalents don't when discussing that field in French.

Comment: @PapaPoule In a few words, a finite sequence would be (x_1, ..., x_n) that stops after a certain rank. Such a sequence is always bounded, but the reverse is not true: (1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, ...) (that never stops) is always bounded between 0 and 1. Measurable would refer to some kind of [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)), in both languages, and it's a completely different topic (doesn't apply to sequences, there are unbounded measurable functions and bounded immeasurable functions). AFAIK "determinable" doesn't have a standard meaning in math [cont.]

Comment: [.inued] so it's not right off the table, but it seems to me a bit of a stretch to assign it a meaning of "boundedness"; it sounds too much like "computable" and the such, that have well-defined meanings in math too. (Sorry if I appear to reject all possibilities randomly, but I'm looking for a word I could use in mathematics, that severely restricts the possibilities...)

Comment: Considering all the downvotes “earned” here by good folks taking the time & making the effort to answer this extremely specific question (with its, IMO, continuously changing, i.e.,contracting parameters), could it be possible that what we have here is an example of the kind of question asked about [here on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237154/a-question-asked-in-order-to-expose-ignorance)? Regardless, & for what it’s worth, according to my personal interpretation of the forum’s “rules,” the “rejection/non-acceptance” of answers does not automatically require downvoting them.

Comment: @PapaPoule No, it is a genuine question (sorry, I had misunderstood your point in my previous comment). I tried to make my requirements relatively clear (I hadn't seen that [tag:mathématiques] was an available tag), and I also tried to explain for each answer what I thought of it. Maybe I could have been clearer. (I am well aware of the SE rules... May I point out that 2 > 1 ? I don't think it's my fault if the answers that were posted were not suitable; I wouldn't chance giving my opinion on terminology for a philosophy concept, for example.)

Comment: I will move on, but not before confirming that you did misunderstand my reason for linking the ELU question. It was not linked for the purpose of calling you ignorant or even implying that you are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je ne sais pas s'il y a un mot accepté ou pas; je ne le connais en tout cas pas. Plus généralement, ce genre de problème, on le rencontre — dans tous les sens — principalement quand on essaye de suivre trop fortement une formulation provenant d'une autre langue. Il faut accepter de s'écarter du mot à mot et de reformuler la proposition, la phrase, le paragraphe. Ici, *la suite est bornée et donc...*

Mais à l'oral, on s'enferme parfois dans des constructions dont il n'est pas possible de sortir sans une certaine lourdeur (ce n'est pas sans raison que j'ai été jusqu'à suggérer une reformulation du paragraphe).  Mais dans ce cas, dire simplement *le caractère borné* est tout aussi possible.

Si on veut absolument un terme — depuis le temps que le concept existe, on peut se demander pourquoi aucun ne s'est apparemment imposé —, il faudra un néologisme.  Les problèmes de *bornitude* sont d'une part qu'*itude* est peu productif en français, d'autre part que le suffixe a des connotations indésirables ici (voir la *négritude* de Césaire et de Sanghor) par exemple, plus que l'utilisation d'un néologisme, je crois que ce sont ces connotations qui suscitent l’hilarité des auditeurs à l'utilisation occasionnelle du terme).  La construction d'autres néologisme à partir de *borne* et des suffixes habituels[1] pour nommer les qualités donnerait *bornence*, *bornescence*, *bornat*, *bornité*, *bornerie*, *bornesse*, *bornise*, *borneur*, *bornisme*.  *Bornence* ou *bornité* me semblent être les seuls choix où le suffixe n'apporte pas de connotations malvenues.

[1] La liste vient d'[ici](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/suffixes.php).

Comment: Il faut à tout prix faire quelque chose avec cette *bornerie*, si personne ne la veut je l'accueille à la maison.

Comment: Le _bornisme_ n'est pas trop mal.  Du moins tant que les _bornites_ ne dépassent pas les _bornes_, renvoyant les _borneurs_ à leur _bornitude_, ne laissant qu'un peu de _bornat_, toute _bornescence_ envolée.

Comment: Moui. Quitte à utiliser un néologisme formé à partir de "borne", je préfère "bornitude" : les gens le comprennent et l'utilisent déjà, même si ça fait rire. Ce n'est pas le cas de bornence et bornité. (Quant aux connotations de "-itude" qui sont mentionnées... Je ne suis pas convaincu du tout que c'est ce qui fasse rire.) Je ne cherche pas forcément un nom qui reprenne la racine de "borne".

Comment: J'accepte pour les deux premiers paragraphes, même si comme j'ai dit je préfère "bornitude" à "bornence" et "bornité" (qui sonnent vraiment bizarre à mes oreilles). Si jamais quelqu'un trouve un nom qui pourrait s'appliquer (pas forcément dérivé du mot "borné") je suis quand même preneur.

Comment: *négritude* de *Sangor*, je pense plutôt à la négritude d'*Aimé Césaire*, thème repris effectivement par *Senghor*

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE, corrigé. Merci.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Pour le *-itude* connoté, ne pas oublier *bravitude* ('brave + attitude'  qui aurait du donner *bravoure* )  d'une ministre française en déplacement en Chine.

Answer (score 2):

Je ne connais moi non plus aucun nom qui aille. Le plus simple est de reformuler la phrase :

> Grâce au fait que la suite soit bornée...
>
> Puisque la suite est bornée...
>
> La suite étant bornée...

... ou bien d'utiliser directement le nom "bornes", puisqu'on parle ici de leur existence même :

> Grâce aux bornes de la suite...

Comment: Tu voulais probablement écrire *aucun **nom** qui aille*, j'imagine. Je n'ai pas osé te corriger d'emblée, je te laisse faire.

Comment: @RomainVALERI tout à fait, merci !

Answer (score 0):

Pour « [boundedness](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=boundedness&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0) » on trouve:

> *limitabilité*
>
> En mathématique, capacité d'admettre des bornes.
>
> [ *TERMIUM Plus®*, la banque de données terminologiques et linguistiques
>   du gouvernement du Canada ]

Voir aussi ailleurs (GDT) « bounded variable » ([variable bornée](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17058562)), « bounded set » ([ensemble borné](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=19077495)).

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr... Peut-être dans certains contextes, mais en mathématiques on fait une différence entre les "-able" et les "-é" (une variété orientable, ce n'est pas la même chose qu'une variété orientée). J'ai l'impression que "limitabilité" voudrait dire que l'on peut borner la suite si on en a envie, mais qu'on ne le fait pas. (C'est peut-être du chipotage de ma part). Et je n'ai trouvé ce mot dans aucun dictionnaire...

Comment: Je ne comprends pas bien ton hostilité. Tu postes une réponse à ma question, elle ne me convient pas, j'aurais juste pu la downvoter et passer à autre chose. Là j'ai pris le temps d'expliquer en quoi ça ne me convient pas, et j'ai bien dit que cela pourrait peut-être convenir dans certains contextes. Me répondre que tu en as "peu à cirer"... Vu que je suis poli je préfère ne pas continuer.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Je t'offre mes excuses ici pour mon commentaire désobligeant. Il ne s'agit pas de mon domaine; je voulais surtout signifier que je n'avais pas envie d'entrer dans les détails. J'éprouve un certain agacement à présenter un élément de terminologie qui couvre exactement le terme présenté, puis à le voir remis en question en commentaire alors que je ne suis pas responsable de la traduction. Je réintègre la réponse, et j'assume. Désolé et merci.

Answer (score 0):

Peut-être pourrait-on utiliser le terme plus général de  **paramétrage**  qui contient la notion de limites.

Comment: Désolé, mais je pense que ça n'a rien à voir... Je ne vois pas du tout en quoi "paramétrage" pourrait convenir.

Comment: Il me semble que si, c'est bien le sens initial de paramétrage. En revanche, il est tellement utilisé lui aussi que cela engendredrait plus de confusion que cela n'en résoudrait, je le crains...

Comment: Non, ça ne marche pas du tout, parce qu'en mathématiques, les mots *paramètre*, *limite* et *borné* désignent des concepts différents.

Comment: Merci, Gilles, la précision est très appréciée.

Comment: Les mathématiques ne sont pas du tout mon domaine  mais j essaye de comprendre le sens de la question. Je suis intriguée par le manque de mot français correspondant à ''boundedness". Est-ce que ''contraintes de bornes" reflète un peu la situation?